# MySQL: function returning select with offset parameter

Tags: mysql

Function `get_summ` must return a value from `SELECT` with specified `OFFSET` which is passed as parameter:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_summ(i INT, o INT)
    RETURNS INT
BEGIN    
    RETURN (SELECT summ FROM orders WHERE id = i LIMIT 1 OFFSET o);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This gives `syntax error near 'o')`.

**Is that possible with MySQL?**

Comment: It works fine when `OFFSET o` is replaced with `OFFSET 1`

Comment: You mean `OFFSET o` is replaced with `OFFSET 1`?

Comment: which version of MySQL are you using? It's only supported in 5.5.6 and above

Comment: Correct, `OFFSET o`.

Comment: 5.1.52. It is a legacy database